# How can I add items to an input using the enter key and only submit the form when i click a button?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-select

I'm using v-select and there is a problem with this plugin... When you press **enter** inside input, it submit to form. How can i add items to input using Enter and only submit the form when i click at **Button**?

[Example Here CODE PEN](https://codepen.io/JacksonJohnson28/pen/YrQENo)

**HTML**

```
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select</h1>
  <p>Try to add items in input using "ENTER"</p>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="submited()">
  <v-select multiselect :options="options"></v-select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: ["some", "thing", "another", "things"]
  },
  methods: {
    submited(){
      alert('submited!')
    }
  }
})
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prevent default on the form and then move the submitted logic to the button.

```js
Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    options: ["some", "thing", "another", "things"]
  },
  methods: {
    submitted() {
      console.log('submited!')
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#app {
  max-width: 35em;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.2.0/dist/vue-select.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h1>Vue Select</h1>
  <p>Try to add items in input using "ENTER"</p>
  <form v-on:submit.prevent="">
    <v-select multiple :options="options"></v-select>
    <button type="button" v-on:click="submitted()">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

See here:
https://codepen.io/uidan/pen/PJjOyb

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to prevent the keypress on the particular component from submitting the form, but want to keep all the other default form behaviors (maybe including pressing Enter while on a different input, for example), you can catch the native keypress events on the component:

```
<v-select multiple :options="options" @keypress.native.prevent=""></v-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved, working perfectly.

```
   <div id="app">
      <h1>Vue Select</h1>
      <p>Try to add items in input using "ENTER"</p>
      <form v-on:submit.prevent="">
      <v-select multiple :value.sync="selected" :options="options"></v-select>
        <button type="submit" @click="submitedd()">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>


Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null,
      options: ["some", "thing", "another", "things"]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submitedd(){
      console.log("i am here");
    }
  }
})
```